# Get all types from compilation using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

I'm trying to get all types by some criteria from Roslyn Compilation created by this code:

```
var syntaxTrees = new[] 
{ 
      CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source, new CSharpParseOptions(LanguageVersion.Preview)) 
};

// Add some references
references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(...));
            
// Create compilation
var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(nameof(GeneratorRunner), syntaxTrees, references, options);

return compilation;
```

Then I'm using this code to seach for types

```
compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("HomeCenter.Messages.Commands.Device.AdjustPowerLevelCommand");
compilation.GetSymbolsWithName(x => true, SymbolFilter.Type).ToList();
```

This works weird for me - GetSymbolsWithName returns only types defined in my sources but not in referenced assemblies but GetTypeByMetadataName is able to return information about type even when it is defined in reference assembly. The problem is I'm trying to search for all types in compilation so I don't know exact names. The question is how can I search in all types application have in sources but also in referenced assemblies? Also is there any other option for filtering opposite to name - I'm interested in all types that inherit from specific type so they can be named in all kind of ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to start searching through all types, you can do Compilation.GlobalNamespace, which gives you a INamespaceSymbol that represents the "root" namespace of the hierarchy. From there you can call GetTypeMembers() to get types that are in that namespace, and GetNamespaceMembers() to get child namespaces. You'll have to do the recursion yourself, I don't think we have a helper for that.

Comment: Ok with this I can find all information I want. Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Just addition to the answer from Jason Malinowski. You can use the following symbol visitor helper:

```
internal class ExportedTypesCollector : SymbolVisitor
{
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
    private readonly HashSet<INamedTypeSymbol> _exportedTypes;

    public ExportedTypesCollector(CancellationToken cancellation, int? estimatedCapacity = null)
    { 
        _cancellationToken = cancellation;
        _exportedTypes = estimatedCapacity.HasValue
            ? new HashSet<INamedTypeSymbol>(estimatedCapacity.Value, SymbolEqualityComparer.Default)
            : new HashSet<INamedTypeSymbol>(SymbolEqualityComparer.Default);
    }

    public ImmutableArray<INamedTypeSymbol> GetPublicTypes() => _exportedTypes.ToImmutableArray();

    public override void VisitAssembly(IAssemblySymbol symbol)
    {
        _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        symbol.GlobalNamespace.Accept(this);
    }

    public override void VisitNamespace(INamespaceSymbol symbol)
    {
        foreach (INamespaceOrTypeSymbol namespaceOrType in symbol.GetMembers())
        {
            _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            namespaceOrType.Accept(this);
        }
    }

    public override void VisitNamedType(INamedTypeSymbol type)
    {
        _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        if (!type.IsAccessibleOutsideOfAssembly() || !_exportedTypes.Add(type))
            return;

        var nestedTypes = type.GetTypeMembers();

        if (nestedTypes.IsDefaultOrEmpty)
            return;

        foreach (INamedTypeSymbol nestedType in nestedTypes)
        {
            _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            nestedType.Accept(this);
        }
    }
}
```

with an extension method `IsAccessibleOutsideOfAssembly` like this:

```
public static bool IsAccessibleOutsideOfAssembly(this ISymbol symbol) =>
        symbol.DeclaredAccessibility switch
        {
            Accessibility.Private => false,
            Accessibility.Internal => false,
            Accessibility.ProtectedAndInternal => false,
            Accessibility.Protected => true,
            Accessibility.ProtectedOrInternal => true,
            Accessibility.Public => true,
            _ => true,    //Here should be some reasonable default
        };
```

Comment: This visitor is great but one thing I'm don't understand. In method VisitNamedType there is type.GetTypeMembers(). When type is a class it is acting wierd for me - it is returning all methods just like types with TypeKind = class? I thouth that GetTypeMembers() will return nasted classes but It is diffrent?

Comment: I checked and it returns nested types for me. You described a really strange behavior. It should return nested types and I never saw it working differently with a type. However, maybe you have delegate declarations in your code? Delegate types are also types and will be returned as well.

Comment: When you run this test https://github.com/dominikjeske/HomeCenter/blob/MotionService/HomeCenter.SourceGenerators.Tests/ActorProxySourceGeneratorTests.cs#L22 and hit breakpoint here https://github.com/dominikjeske/HomeCenter/blob/MotionService/HomeCenter.SourceGenerators/Extensions/TypeVisitor.cs#L54 you have for example HomeCenter.SourceGenerators.Tests.MessageGenerator.<PublishEvent>d__0 this is TypeKind of class. But this is not the onlyone.

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't installed .net 5 yet and worked with it. I can't build MotionService branch in your repo and debug the test. Changing dependencies to .net core 3.1 didn't work out. I won't solve the dependency issues cause ii will take a lot of my time. But if you can create a branch which contains the code with issue and doesn't depend on .net 5 then I can try to debug it. Or you can try to debug into Roslyn yourself with Visual Studio 2019 which supports the decompilation and debugging in decompiled sources

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue - GetTypeMembers is returning internal methods.

Comment: is there any difference between `nestedType.Accept(this);` and `VisitNamedType(nestedType);` ?

Comment: In general, for a visitor pattern there is a difference. 
Usually, internally `Accept` method is overridden in the concrete visited type with a call to a proper visitor method. So, the visited type itself calls the correct visitor method, that is best to handle it. This way the correct method is determined both by the type of the visitor and the visited type. This technique is called "double dispatch". You can read about it here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/visitor-pattern-in-c-sharp-5-versions/

Comment: On the other hand, `VisitNamedType(nestedType)` is just a particular direct call to the `VisitNamedType` method. 

To feel the difference, imagine that there are two types in the hierarchy - `NamedTypeSymbol` which is accepted by the visitor's `VisitNamedType` method and a derived `FancyNamedTypeSymbol` and there is a method `VisitFancyNamedType`. 

Internally, `NamedTypeSymbol` overrides `Accept` method  to call visitor's  `VisitNamedType` method. And `FancyNamedTypeSymbol` overrides `Accept` method once more to call `VisitFancyNamedType` method.

Comment: Now, imagine that `nestedType` variable has type `NamedTypeSymbol` but it stores an object of a `FancyNamedTypeSymbol`. Now if you call `visitor.VisitNamedType(nestedType)`, then `VisitNamedType` will be executed. But if you call, `nestedType.Accept(visitor)` then an `Accept` overload from the `FancyNamedTypeSymbol` will be executed which will call `VisitFancyNamedType`.

Comment: Of course, this is imaginary example. Deriving one non-abstract visited type from another non-abstract visited type is not a good visitor pattern implementation, and an anti-pattern. The difference between `Accept` and direct call to `VisitXXX` is confusing can be easily missed which leads to the execution of a wrong method for a visited type.

Comment: Roslyn visitors and types are designed amazingly well. There is no non-abstract type derived from another non-abstract type. Thus, in Roslyn you won't encounter this difference. But in general, it exists and it is useful to be aware of it.